# Responsive Web Design with Bootstrap CSS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, responsive-design, navigation

I have built a site that I am trying to make responsive...with Bootstrap CSS it is actually fairly easy - but I am running into a weird problem. Everything works fine...except when I visit one page (the "Settings" page), when I'm holding my iPhone upright...the links stop working in the navbar (I try to click on them but nothing happens). However, if I turn my iPhone, and hold it horizontally, the navbar links start working again. Has anyone ever seen this problem? Here is relevant code:

navbar.html (I am using angular, and it doesn't make sense for the nav buttons to function on one page...and not on another):

```
<div class="header" ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
  <h2 id="redbox" class="text-muted">[H]</h2><h3 class="text-muted">ackabox</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
    <li ng-repeat="item in menu" ng-class="{active: isActive(item.link)}">
        <a ng-href="{{item.link}}">{{item.title}}</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-hide="currentUser" ng-class="{active: isActive('/login')}"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
    <li ng-show="currentUser" ng-class="{active: isActive('/settings')}"><a href="/settings">Settings</a></li>
    <li ng-hide="currentUser" ng-class="{active: isActive('/signup')}"><a href="/signup">Sign up</a></li>
    <li ng-show="currentUser" ng-class="{active: isActive('/logout')}"><a href="" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I don't really know what else to include for code...it just seems like a glitch with responsive web design that might have some weird solution I don't know about. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I posted the site to git: https://github.com/eamonwhiter73/hackabox

Node modules are included...you just have to run MongoDB instance...and then `cd` to the site directory in your console...and type `grunt serve`. That will load the site automatically into the browser on `localhost:9000`.

Also, for MongoDB to function - mind this line in `lib/config/env/development.js`:

```
...

uri: 'mongodb://localhost/hackabox'

...
```

You may have to change this depending on how you have MongoDB set up on your computer (I am on a Mac, but I know that for Windows, it might be a slightly different syntax - or you may be using a username and password...just google it).

Have at it (and check out the cool forum that I built into the site)!

Comment: Try if the error persists in a resized browser window, and check the error console.

Comment: @parchment good news kind of - it has the same error in a resized browser window...does this help u at all?

Comment: @parchment if i expand the window again...it will start working agian.

Comment: @parchment - when i was messing with the css - i removed some stuff that was like `* {box-sizing: xxx}` from the bootstrap.css - would i need to put that back to get rid of the glitch? - not sure why bootstrap has the `box-sizing` thing for everything...never really payed much attention to that css attribute.

Comment: it's possible, certainly. Try using a fresh bootstrap.css to see if it fixes your problem. But other than that (and checking the error console), honestly I have no idea how to fix this...

Comment: @parchment tried using fresh bootstrap.css - still having the problem...so it isn't bootstrap - can u think of anything else?

Comment: @parchment i noticed that i was using bootstrap v3.1.1 - i am updating to v3.2.0 to see if this resolves the error.

Comment: @parchment updating to 3.2.0 did not resolve the error.

Comment: @parchment this is so weird...I changed the line in my index.html that deals with the responsive stuff from `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.88">` to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` (the way it was before...without `initial-scale`) and it is still having the problem...so it doesn't even have anything to do with it being scaled...this is really confusing.

Comment: Can you post the angular app somehow?

Comment: @parchment yah sure - ill make a git repo and post the link

Comment: @parchment i am using the `yo angular-fullstack` seed - you would need to have mongo running - and if ur on windows u would have to change the mongo uri in the code (i develop on mac)...other than that - if u get the repo i make...and then turn on mongo...and do `grunt serve` in console in project folder...that should get the site going.

Comment: @parchment here is the link - i included all the npm modules with the upload...so just run mongo...and do `grunt serve` https://github.com/eamonwhiter73/hackabox

Comment: @parchment - to see what is going on ... u need to create a user for the site (sign up in the top right corner) and then you will see the "settings" link appear in the top right menu - u click on that...resize the browser..and try to click on one of the links in that menu...and u will see the problem

Comment: @parchment tizz a doozy lol

Comment: @parchment - i figured out one thing - if i remove `class="header"` from this line `<div class="header" ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">` in app/views/partials/navbar.html - it makes it so the two buttons being loaded by the `ng-repeat` work - but the logout button still is frozen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the real culprit - oddly enough - it was just a `float:left` in the `css` for `.header > h2` and `.header > h3` - when I removed that it fixed everything - need to figure out a different way to reformat my header though :)